# Broadcast Receiver is called every time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

Don't downvote it.. If you think question needs clarification then comment the issue.

I want to update my sqlite table at midnight so calling broadcast receiver to hit at midnight automatically i.e. without launching the app. But it is updating **every time when I launch the app.**

Code:-

calling the function in the mainActivity.java in `onCreate()`

```
private void setTheTimeToUpdateTables(Context context) {

        Log.i("Update table function","Yes");

        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(context,UpdateTables.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        alarmStartTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


        System.out.println("Updating table time "+alarmStartTime);
        System.out.println("Time in millseconds "+alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis());


        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

        Log.d("Alarm","Set for midnight");

    }
```

public class UpdateTables extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
DbHelper dbHelper;
ArrayList<ListMedicine> reminderInfo;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    dbHelper=new DbHelper(context);
    Log.i("Service Start", CalculateDaysService.TAG);

    context.startService(new Intent(context,CalculateDaysService.class));



    Log.i("Done","Yes");
}
}
```

Issue:- 1. This broadcast receiver is called everytime whenever I am launching the app.
         2. It is not called at the midnight.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are making a `Calendar` whose time is in the past. This causes the alarm to trigger immediately. You need to add one day after setting the hour to zero.

Second, `setInexactRepeating()` will not make it trigger at midnight. I suggest you read the documentation for that method as well as the other methods of `AlarmManager`, because it sounds like you should be using one of the `setExact()` methods.

Comment: if I use set exact method then it will only call once that what I understand from documentation @Karakuri

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal so make another call to `setExact()` after your work is done to schedule the next wake up.